# How can I delete unversioned files in Bazaar?

Tags: dvcs, bazaar

How can I remove all unversioned files from a Bazaar workspace?  I'm looking to do the equivalent of `hg purge --all` or `git clean -fd`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this only in [BzrTools](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrTools), as the clean-tree command.

Comment: It was installed by default in a virgin copy of Bazaar 2.0, so its functionality has apparently been merged.  That said, I'm disappointed that "bzr help" didn't show that command, or anything about it.

Comment: Actually command named `clean-tree.` If you have `bzrtools` plugin installed you'll see this command in the output of `bzr help commands`. To check is you have `bzrtools` plugin installed run `bzr plugins` command.

Comment: According to `bzr plugins`, I do not have `bzrtools` installed; just `netrc_credential_store` and `launchpad`.  According to `bzr help`, I have no `clean-tree` command.  Yet `bzr help clean-tree` shows me the help for `clean-tree`, and executing `bzr clean-tree` works just fine.  So, while I'm happy, the above information is either out-of-date or confused, as near as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

Benjamin Pollack said:

> According to bzr help, I have no
>   clean-tree command. Yet bzr help
>   clean-tree shows me the help for
>   clean-tree, and executing bzr
>   clean-tree works just fine.

`bzr help` only shows a summary of the most commonly used commands.  To see all available commands, use `bzr help commands`.

(Sorry to answer instead of comment ... I don't have sufficient reputation yet)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a bash one liner for this:

> rm -i $(bzr status -S | grep "^?" | cut -d ? -f 2- )